# Bridged Networking not working on Windows 7 Guest (Windows 10 Host)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, windows-10

I can't seem to get bridged networking to work on my host (Windows 10).  NAT works just fine with the guest (Windows 7).  The Host is connected via wifi to my network.  I'm using Virtualbox v5.0.8.  When I boot it up using Bridged networking it is assigned an IP address of 169.254.131.227.  Any recommendations of what I should try?

[image: Snapshot of settings]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Firewall is allowing VirtualBox access through.

A 169.254.x.x IP is called an 'Autoconfiguration IP' and was developed by Microsoft and Apple to allow hosts to automatically join an ad hoc network when the network card finds a connection but no DHCP server.  So you can take 8 computers, hook them to a basic switch and, with no configuration, they'll all be on the same LAN segment.  Which is all to say, that the guest is connecting to the network but not reaching a DHCP server.

Make sure the firewall is allowing traffic.  Also, check MAC filtering.  If it's on, try allow the guest MAC.

Finally, I'm assuming you've set up the bridge in VirtualBox.  Make sure that is set up properly as well.  Probably the best first step.